# Selecting ALL Max Values SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am working with two tables in this query `Table 1: admit`, `Table 2: Billing.`
What I want to do is show people who are admitted to our crisis services `(program codes '44282' and '44283')`. For these people, I want to show their insurance, which is under the field `guarantor_id` in the Billing Table. To do this, I need to show ALL the max coverage effective dates `cov_effective_date` where the coverage effective date is less than the admission date `preadmit_admission_date` and the coverage expiration date `cov_expiration_date` is greater than the admission date (or Is Null).  The code I have right now does everything I want, but doesn’t get all the max coverage effective dates. So if someone had two different insurances that began on the same date it will only show one and I want it show both.

```
Select 
 A.patid
,A.episode_number
,A.preadmit_admission_date
,A.program_code
,A.program_value
,A.c_date_of_birth
,A.guarantor_id
,max(A.cov_effective_date) as "MaxDate"

from(

Select
  SA.patid
 ,SA.episode_number
 ,SA.preadmit_admission_date
 ,SA.program_code
 ,SA.program_value
 ,SA.c_date_of_birth
 ,BGE.guarantor_id
 ,BGE.cov_effective_date

 From System.view_episode_summary_admit as "SA"

 Left Outer Join

 (Select 
   BG.patid
  ,BG.episode_number
  ,BG.guarantor_id
  ,BG.cov_effective_date
  ,BG.cov_expiration_date

  from System.billing_guar_emp_data as "BG"

  Inner Join

  (Select patid, episode_number, preadmit_admission_date
  from System.view_episode_summary_admit ) as "A"
  On
  (A.patid = BG.patid) and (A.episode_number = BG.episode_number)

  Where
  BG.cov_effective_date <= preadmit_admission_date and
 (BG.cov_expiration_date >= preadmit_admission_date or
  BG.cov_expiration_date  Is Null)
  ) as "BGE"
  on
 (BGE.patid = SA.patid) and (BGE.episode_number = SA.episode_number)

  Where
  (program_code = '44282' or program_code = '44283' )
   and preadmit_admission_date >= {?Start Date}
   and preadmit_admission_date <= {?End Date}
   ) A

   Group By Patid, Episode_number
```

Comment: Sorry low on time or this would be a full answer.  This query won't operate on most SQL languages and will throw an error, when using aggreagtes you need all non-aggregate columns in the group by.  MySQL likes to skip the error and randomly grab values for columns not in group by.  So lets get rid of that aggregate.  You have subquerying down...write a subquery that gets the max date by your key, join it to the rest of your statement, and refer to it from there.  If you need further help, I'll have something up in a couple of hours for you.

Comment: @Twelfth Ok, thanks! I will work on that.

Comment: @Twelfth I tried following your instructions, but I am still have trouble getting my query to work. If you have still have time, I would love to see what you come up with!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I beleive that BG.cov_effective_date comes from System.billing_guar_emp_data.  Would this statement get the date you are calling "maxdate" in your results?    select patid, max(cov_effective_date) from System.billing_guar_emp_data group by patid

Comment: @Twelfth Yes Bg.cov_effective_date comes from System.billing_guar_emp_data.

Comment: @Strawberry Ok, I will work on making a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is such a psuedo answer.

```
Select (your fields)
from (your entire query)bg
left join
   (select patid, max(cov_effective_date) maxdate from  system.billing_guar_emp_data group by patid) maxdate
on maxdate.patid = bg.patidate
```

Remove the group bys for the aggregate...you can now refer to maxdate.maxdate as a field in your opening select statement.   Might be a better place to join this maxdate than joined at the very end of the query (possibly right under BG in the from statement), but psuedo code right? :)  Hopefully you can apply the concept, let me know I'm free (freer?) in the afternoon if you need more.

Comment: Sweet, I changed the left join to an inner join, and joined on the episode number, and date as well as patid, and it worked! Thanks for the help!